# Eclipse unable to recognize Google python-api-client library

Tags: python, eclipse, google-api, google-api-python-client

This is literally strange thing.

Eclipse is unable to recognize Google's [api-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) in Django project. I could even do `GData`.

This is a simple `import` I am trying to do

`from apiclient.discovery import build`

Eclipse is showing red underline saying `Unresolved import: build`

However, the same thing is perfectly working in IDLE, PyScripter.

I checked the python path in Eclipse and its all fine (how could I import other libraries otherwise).

So, whats going on and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import discovery instead of build, i.e.

```
from apiclient import discovery
...
discovery.build(...)
```

I had the same problem and it worked for me. See [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-api-python-client/import%2420build%2420/google-api-python-client/cHjFXOb4n-M/gD3_Xk6K1HUJ) .